# Font size for annotations

Tags: r, annotations, plotly

I made my visualisation. Everything is fine and I use the annotations to add a legend title, just I would like the title to have a slightly larger font.

I paste below a self contained example. Can anyone tell me how to fine tune the font for the "Place of sale"?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(pander)


df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L
), sales = c("Extra EU28", "Extra EU28", "Extra EU28", "Extra EU28", 
"Extra EU28", "Extra EU28", "Extra EU28", "Extra EU28", "EU27", 
"EU27", "EU27", "EU27", "EU27", "EU27", "EU27", "EU27", "UK", 
"UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK"), value = c(307291L, 
430688L, 483915L, 600302L, 635004L, 596056L, 589990L, 651232L, 
518325L, 613219L, 683995L, 631424L, 615276L, 645861L, 703329L, 
778710L, 254019L, 337912L, 278370L, 326557L, 326080L, 341547L, 
369812L, 376858L)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), .Names = c("year", 
"sales", "value"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

legendtitle <- list(yref='paper',xref="paper",y=.65,x=1.1, text="Place of    Sale"  ,  showarrow=F) 


p1 <- plot_ly(df1 , x = ~year, y = ~value, color = ~sales, linetype = ~sales,
          symbol=~sales,   marker = list(size = 10),  colors = "Set1",
          type = 'scatter',
          mode = 'lines+markers'              ) %>%  layout( yaxis =      list(rangemode = "tozero",title = "Number of Eggs",
 titlefont=list(size=18)),
xaxis = list(title = "Year", titlefont=list(size=18))) %>%     layout(title="Eggs Produced in the UK", titlefont=list(size=24), annotations=legendtitle)%>% layout( margin = list( t=40, pad=1)) %>%  layout(legend = list(x = 1, y = 0.5))


htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p1, "eggs_plot.html")
```

Comment: `legendtitle <- list(yref='paper',xref="paper",y=.65,x=1.2, text="Place of Sale",  showarrow=F, font = list(size = 24)) `

Answer (score 4):

Just add the corresponding attribute to the annotations object:

```
legendtitle <- list(yref='paper',xref="paper",y=.65,x=1.2, 
                    text="Place of Sale",  showarrow=F, 
                    font = list(size = 24))
```

See [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-scene-annotations-font).